# Using google sheets as a json source for a Twilio studio whitelist/blacklist

Tags: twilio

I've gotten pretty close to using google sheets as a source to maintain a twilio blacklist/whitelist but I am sure I am missing something obvious at this point - this just comes down to my general poor json skills

I created a function: https://forwardvmtoboris-7546.twil.io/path_2  ( I left it poblic for now since there is nothing confidential there)  and this seems to return json as far as studio is concerned

(source for those interested because this was a pain to get working:  https://pastebin.com/raw/WV75JkU0 )

which does finally return proper json as far as I can tell/test:

Request URL: https://forwardvmtoboris-7546.twil.io/path_2
Request Method: POST
Response Status Code: 200
Response Content Type: application/json

with the correct response:

https://pastebin.com/raw/0j716tNN

etc

just to check - running this through jq via .table.rows[].c[].v preduces the number list

my understanding is that studio requires json objects so I would use  .tables.rows which seems to return objects

no matter what variant I try I am obviously missing the proper way to express this in liquid on the subsequent widget, no matter what I try I get

such as:

```
    {{ widgets.function_1.parsed.table.rows }}

    {{ widgets.function_1.parsed }}

    {{ widgets.function_1.parsed.body }}
```

Input evaluated to '+1234' from '{{trigger.call.From}}'
Transitioning to 'VM_Greeting' because '+1234" that's on the list of numbers did not match any expression

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We've had [this conversation on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/twilio/comments/q9o2ra/using_google_sheets_as_a_json_source_for_a_twilio/) but I'll reiterate here for anyone else that comes across this question.

Studio does not have any concept of looping through data using liquid variables, so returning arrays of data is not that useful the next widget.

Instead, I would recommend doing the work to calculate the result of your block/allow list from the function. If you pass in the incoming phone number  to the function, calculate whether the number is blocked or allowed and return that from the function.

```js
const request = require('request');  

exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {  
  var phoneNumber = event.phoneNumber;
  var options = {  
           url:    context.SHEETS_URL,  
           method: 'GET'
  }  
  request(options, function(error, response, body){  
    var from = body.indexOf("{");
    var to   = body.lastIndexOf("}")+1;

    var jsonText = body.slice(from, to);

    var parsedText = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    if (functionToCalculateWhetherNumberIsBlocked(phoneNumber, parsedText) {
      callback(null, "blocked");
    } else {
      callback(null, "allowed");
    }
  })  
 };
```

The above function returns the text "blocked" or "allowed" based on the number and the list from your spreadsheet.

With this, you can then inspect the `{{ widgets.function_1.body }}` in a Split widget and match against "blocked" or "allowed".

Answer (score -1):

ditto for anybody who finds this later - this actually worked by doing a "split on" widget.body "contains" test inside studio natively!

Update: No it doesn't lol - going to do it via function

thanks again